# cant set the size of a multi line text box mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea

can anyone tell me why this wont work ? no matter what I use for cols & rows, the text box is always the same size

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Report.EmailMessage,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 100, @rows = 20 } })

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the html attributes and the below code should work.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Report.EmailMessage, new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 100, @rows = 20 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could employ the following overload for `TextAreaFor`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    int rows,
    int columns,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Producing:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Report.EmailMessage, 20, 100, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

[Relevant link to MSDN article.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textareafor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.TextAreaExtensions.TextAreaFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Object%29)